# d3.js scale-chromatic is not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have json data:

```
{
  "nodes": 
  [{"id": "Michael Scott"}, 
   {"id": "Jim Halpert"}, 
   {"id": "Pam Beasley"}
  ], 
  "links": 
  [{"source": "Michael Scott", "target": "Jim Halpert", "value": 50}, 
   {"source": "Michael Scott", "target": "Pam Beasley", "value": 25}
  ]
}
```

I have code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #aaa;
}

.nodes circle {
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 40px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("data.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line");

  var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateBlues);

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

</script>
```

This results in a force-directed graph without the nodes colored. Why aren't the nodes colored by the `var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateBlues);` line coupled with the `.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); })` line? Is it because `value` is attached to the links and not to the nodes? If so, how would I alter the code to show a color scale for the links?

Thank you for any insight you all may have!

Comment: Your links have a property named `value`, but your nodes do not (if you use `console.log(d.value)` before the return statement `return color(d.value);`, it will be undefined, which is why it shows as black). If you give each node (as opposed to link) a property named `value` you should find more success - but if you want each node to be colored based on a sum or product of all the links that touch it, your logic will need to be a bit more complex.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can definitely see how that would be more complex. I'm realizing it might be better just to color the links instead. Do you know of a resource for that off the top of your head?

Comment: You can color the links pretty much as you were with the attempt to color the nodes (make sure to move where you define the color scale up a bit). To counter the css you can either remove the css styles on links and use `.attr` or you can use `.style` and keep the css styles on links. Also I would take a look at [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/de07fcf34538cd6f8459e17038563ed3), and use something like:  `var color = d3.scaleSequential().domain([20,60]).interpolator(d3.interpolateBlues);`, or use some function to set your domain automatically.

Comment: I've used your code to color links [here](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/6a56c744b4e864a2eaa3d35997bb381e).

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much!